# i am trying to push the pseudo element to the left with negative value of the margin left when the parent element is active but it's not working

Tags: html, css

```
   <!-- how to solve this -->

    <!-- language: lang-html and css-->

     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <style>
```

here is styled the button and gived it a relative position

```
 .button {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

here I created the pseudo element and margin-left is working as the button is not in the active situation

```
 .button:after {
  content: "";
  background: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 40px !important;
  margin-top: -120%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: all 3s
 }
```

and here where is my problem margin-left is not working when the button is active

```
 .button:active:after {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-left: -20px;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: 2s
     }
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>

    <h2>Animated Button - Ripple Effect</h2>

    <button class="button">Click Me</button>

    </body>
    </html>


<!-- what could I do to solve this problem -->
```

what is the matter

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
.button::after {

  margin-left: -20px; !important;
}
```

The `!important` value overrides anything that tries to change: `.button::after {  margin-left:`   That would include this:

```
.button:active::after {
 
  margin-left: 0
}
```

That's exactly why the use of `!important` has always been discouraged. If you try to learn anything from W3School, be aware that their code is far from perfect. In the example below, the `!important` is commented out and `.button:active::after` has a `-40px` left margin -- now the fX is upside down.

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  margin-left: -20px; /*!important;*/
  margin-top: -120%;
  padding-top: 300%;
  padding-left: 350%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active::after {
  margin-left: -40px; /* change to margin: -40px for different fx */
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0s
}
```

```html
<h2>Animated Button - Ripple Effect</h2>

<button class="button">Click Me</button>
```